# running oracle s.procedure within dapper .net core

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I am given a stored procedure with content like this;

```
PROCEDURE get_freeboxlocations_cust (
      bundleid     IN       VARCHAR2,
      cityid       IN       VARCHAR2,
      customerid   IN       VARCHAR2,
      statusid     IN       VARCHAR,
      outcursor    OUT      sys_refcursor
   )
   AS
      invalid_parameter   EXCEPTION;
      v_isrange           VARCHAR2 (2);
   BEGIN
      IF (bundleid = '' OR cityid = '' OR customerid = '')
      THEN
         RAISE invalid_parameter;
      END IF;
...
```

I need to execute this query in .net core and get the rows as list of object so here is what I do to achieve this;

```
   using (var dbConn = new OracleConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("OraConnection")))
        {
            dbConn.Open();
            var parameters = new { bundleid = "LI", cityid = "DXB", statusid = '5', customerid = "101" };
            var query = dbConn.Query<BoxLocation>("POBOXSERVICE_PACK.GET_FREEBOXLOCATIONS_CUST", parameters, commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        }
```

I get following error when run the code;

> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005):
> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of
> arguments in call to 'GET_FREEBOXLOCATIONS_CUST' ORA-06550: line 1,
> column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored    at
> OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl.VerifyExecution(Int32&
> cursorId, Boolean bThrowArrayBindRelatedErrors, SqlStatementType
> sqlStatementType, Int32 arrayBindCount, OracleException&
> exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean& hasMoreRowsInDB, Boolean
> bFirstIterationDone)    at
> OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExecuteReader(String
> commandText, OracleParameterCollection paramColl, CommandType
> commandType, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl,
> OracleDataReaderImpl& rdrImpl, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64
> clientInitialLOBFS, OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl, Int64[]
> scnForExecution, Int64[]& scnFromExecution, OracleParameterCollection&
> bindByPositionParamColl, Boolean& bBindParamPresent, Int64&
> internalInitialLOBFS, Int64 internalInitialJSONFS, OracleException&
> exceptionForArrayBindDML, OracleConnection connection, IEnumerable`1
> adrianParsedStmt, Boolean isDescribeOnly, Boolean isFromEF)

I don't know why I receive this and how to fix, any idea?

Comment: I don't know Dapper etc, but doesn't the procedure take five parameters? It looks like you are passing four.

Comment: Also, why does `statusid ` require a different datatype to the other parameters? And `invalid_parameter` is local to the procedure, so the calling code will just get a generic "Unhandled user defined exception" error, but that doesn't matter because `bundleid = ''` can never be true.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment, but your procedure is not going to raise an exception as, in Oracle, `''` is identical to `NULL` and an `= NULL` comparison is never going to be true.

To fix the procedure you need to use `IS NULL` rather than `= ''`:

```sql
PROCEDURE get_freeboxlocations_cust (
  bundleid     IN       VARCHAR2,
  cityid       IN       VARCHAR2,
  customerid   IN       VARCHAR2,
  statusid     IN       VARCHAR,
  outcursor    OUT      sys_refcursor
)
AS
  invalid_parameter   EXCEPTION;
  v_isrange           VARCHAR2 (2);
BEGIN
  IF bundleid IS NULL OR cityid IS NULL OR customerid IS NULL
  THEN
    RAISE invalid_parameter;
  END IF;
  -- ...
END;
/
```

Comment: Well unfortunately its not the case there somehow parameters not bind to procedure

Comment: @TyForHelpDude This is secondary to your problem with Dapper. Once you get an answer from someone who knows .net and dapper and can get your client application to connect to the database and call the procedure then, after that, you will find that your procedure does not behave as expected. This is fixing that secondary problem (which you did not know you had); unfortunately, I do not know dapper so I cannot help you with your primary problem.